# Sorting values in a dictionary Python 3 - Highscores

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I've seen a couple of similar questions but I never really get these answers like importing `OrderedDict`, or this

```
genexp = ((name, dictScore[name]) for name in sorted(dictScore, key=dictScore.get, reverse=True))
        for k, v in genexp:
            print(k, v)
```

So

I'm making a trivia game which records the scores of the players and I want to store them in a file in a descending order. So when I print them out, the highscores show top 1 to n

Here's my code

```
scoreReader = open("highscore.csv","r")
for line in scoreReader:
    line = line[0:-1]
    name, score  = line.split(",")
    dictScore[Snumber] = {name: score}
    Snumber = Snumber+1

print(dictScore)
sorted_dict = sorted(dictScore.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print(sorted_dict)  
scoreReader.close()
```

it doesn't sort the values so idk what to do. HALP

Comment: The line `line = line[0:-1]` isn't doing anything just so you know. It's just setting `line` equal to itself.

Answer (score 3):

If:

```
d = {'Ian': 10, 'Dan': 8, 'Joe': 15}
```

then

```
>>> sorted(d.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
[('Joe', 15), ('Ian', 10), ('Dan', 8)]
```

I'm not sure what `operator` is in your code but this will achieve what you want. You can read more about they `key` parameter and sorting [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)